# Batches over groups

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, grouping, batch-processing

I need to process rows in a table in batches of not less than N rows. Each batch needs to contain an entire group of rows (group is just another column) i.e. when I select top N rows from the table for processing, I need to extend that N to cover the last group in the batch rather than splitting the last group between batches.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE test01 (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
                   , person_name NVARCHAR(100)
                   , person_surname NVARCHAR(100)
                   , person_group_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO
    dbo.test01 (person_name
              , person_surname
              , person_group_code)
VALUES
  ('n1', 's1', 'g1')
, ('n2', 's2', 'g1')
, ('n3', 's3', 'g1')
, ('n4', 's4', 'g1')
, ('n5', 's5', 'g2')
, ('n6', 's6', 'g2')
, ('n7', 's7', 'g2')
, ('n8', 's8', 'g2')
, ('n9', 's9', 'g2')
, ('n10', 's10', 'g2')
, ('n11', 's11', 'g3')
, ('n12', 's12', 'g3')
, ('n13', 's13', 'g3')
, ('n14', 's14', 'g3');
```

My current attempt:

```
DECLARE @batch_start INT = 1
      , @batch_size INT = 5;
DECLARE @max_id INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dbo.test01);

WHILE @batch_start <= @max_id
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.test01
        WHERE id BETWEEN @batch_start AND @batch_start + @batch_size - 1;

        SELECT @batch_start += @batch_size;
    END;

DROP TABLE dbo.test01;
```

In the example above, I am splitting the 14 rows into 3 batches: 5 rows in batch #1, another 5 rows in batch #2 and then 4 rows in the final batch.

The first batch (id from 1 to 5) covers only fraction of the 'g2' group so I need to extend this batch to cover rows 1-10 (I need to process the entire g2 in a single batch).

(by the way, I don't mind batch upsizing - I need to make sure I cover at least one full group per batch).

The result would be that batch #1 would cover groups g1 and g2 (10 rows) then batch #2 would cover group g3 (4 rows) and there would be no batch #3 at all.

Now, the table is billions of rows and batch sizes are around 50K-100K each so I need a solution that performs well.

Any hints on how to approach this with minimal performance hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I've noticed is that your current code assumes no gaps in the identity column - However that is a mistake. An identity column may (and often do) have gaps in the numbers - so the first thing you want to do is use `row_number() over(order by id)` to get a continuous running number for all your records.

The second thing I've added as a column that gave a numeric id for each group ordered by the same order as the identity column - using a well-known technique for solving [gaps and islands](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives/chapter-5) problems.

I've used a table variable to store this data for each id on the source table for the purpose if this demonstration, but you might want to use a temporary table and add indexes on the relevant columns to improve performance.

I've also renamed your `@batch_size` variable to `@batch_min_size` and added a few other variables.

So here is the table variable I've used:

```
DECLARE @Helper As Table (Id int, Rn int, GroupId int)
INSERT INTO @Helper (Id, Rn, GroupId)
SELECT  Id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) As Rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_group_code ORDER BY ID) As GroupId        
FROM dbo.test01
```

This is the content of this table:

```
Id  Rn  GroupId
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5   4
6   6   4
7   7   4
8   8   4
9   9   4
10  10  4
11  11  10
12  12  10
13  13  10
14  14  10
```

I've used a while loop to do the batches.
In the loop, I've used this table to calculate the first and last id of each batch, as well as the last row number of the batch.
Then all I had to do was to use the first and last id in the where clause of the original table:

```
DECLARE @batch_min_size int = 10
      , @batch_end int = 0
      , @batch_start int
      , @first_id_of_batch int
      , @last_id_of_batch int
      , @total_row_count int;

SELECT @total_row_count = COUNT(*) FROM @test01 

WHILE @batch_end < @total_row_count 
BEGIN

    SELECT @batch_start = @batch_end + 1;

    SELECT @batch_end = MAX(Rn)
         , @first_id_of_batch = MIN(Id)
         , @last_id_of_batch = MAX(Id) 
    FROM @Helper 
    WHERE Rn >= @batch_start 
    AND GroupId <= 
    (
        SELECT MAX(GroupId)
        FROM @Helper
        WHERE Rn <= @batch_start + @batch_min_size - 1 
    )


    SELECT id, person_name, person_surname, person_group_code
    FROM dbo.test01 
    WHERE Id >= @first_id_of_batch 
    AND Id <= @last_id_of_batch 

END
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/ODF55397)

Comment: Re "your current code assumes no gaps in the identity column" - yes it is a valid point; in my case though it is an "insert-only" scenario so the identity values are gapless.

Comment: @PiotrL until an insert statement fails... if it does, the identity column will have gaps.

Comment: Fair enough. Great, detailed answer by the way. I will test the logic on my dataset (probably not before January though) and see how it goes. Larger picture: if I eliminate group splits, I can safely replace downstream MERGE with a simple INSERT which will greatly improve performance of the entire process.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

See if below helps:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(g_record_count  int, groupname  varchar(50) )
```

`insert into #Temp(g_record_count,groupname)  SELECT MAX(id),person_group_code FROM dbo.test01 group by person_group_code`

After this loop through this temporary table :

```
DECLARE @rec_per_batch INT = 1
 WHILE @batch_start <= @max_id
BEGIN
    select min(g_record_count) into @rec_per_batch from #temp where  g_record_count>=@batch_size * @batch_start;

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.test01
    WHERE id BETWEEN @batch_start AND  @rec_per_batch;

    SELECT @batch_start += @batch_size;
END;
```